# Set node positions using Graphviz in Jupyter Python

Tags: python, position, nodes, jupyter, graphviz

I want to make a graph with random node positions but it seems that the "pos" attribute for nodes does nothing. Here is a minimal example:

```
import graphviz
import pylab
from graphviz import Digraph

g = Digraph('G', filename='ex.gv',format='pdf')
g.attr(size='7')
g.node('1',pos='1,2')
g.node('2',pos='2,3')
g.node('3',pos='0,0')
g.edge('1','2')
g.edge('1','3')
graphviz.Source(g)
```

Any ideas of how achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although not 100% clear in the docs, I think *pos* is not supported in the dot engine on input. The **fdp** or **neato** engines do support *pos* on input for setting the *initial* position, and if you end the coordinate specification with '!', the coordinates will not change and thus become the final node position.

Play with a live example at https://beta.observablehq.com/@magjac/placing-graphviz-nodes-in-fixed-positions

This standalone python script generates a pdf with the expected node positions:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import graphviz
from graphviz import Digraph

g = Digraph('G', engine="neato", filename='ex.gv',format='pdf')
g.attr(size='7')
g.node('1',pos='1,2!')
g.node('2',pos='2,3!')
g.node('3',pos='0,0!')
g.edge('1','2')
g.edge('1','3')
g.render()
```

Since SO does not support pdf uploading, here's a png image generated with the same code except format='png':

[image]

Without the exclamation marks you get:

[image]

Without any pos attributes at all you get a similar (but not exactly the same) result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, fdp or neato engines seems to output the same result without  the pos attribute

Comment: Maybe you didn't put an exclamation mark at the end of the coordinate specification? See https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:point.
I've updated my answer to make it clear that this is needed in your case.

Comment: The "!" didn´t do the trick in  python, on you live example it work though

Comment: I've updated the answer with working Python code. I'm not sure what the `graphviz.Source(g)` in your code does, but it didn't generate any graph for me at least. Either that's your problem or it might be the Jupyter environment you are using. Perhaps an old Graphviz version there?

Comment: The documentation is explicit about which engines support POS: "In neato and fdp, pos can be used to set the initial position of a node".  Source: https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/pos/